# AWS Network Load Balancer and bridge mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I've configured two load balancers on AWS:
1) Application load balancer with one target group on HTTPS and SSL certificate that point to a nodejs application on port 5000
2) Network load balancer with TCP Listeners on 80 and 443 pointing to nginx (openresty + lua for dynamic certificates generation) routing request to nodejs application on port 5000

Both ELB pointing to the same cluster and same service:

```
"loadBalancers": [
{
"containerName": "uppo-kb",
"targetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:496080483451:targetgroup/ecs-Uppo-uppo-kb/6965729827dccb83",
"containerPort": 5000
},
{
"containerName": "uppo-nginx",
"targetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:496080483451:targetgroup/nginx-80/1797fbb0e9dbc8db",
"containerPort": 80
},
{
"containerName": "uppo-nginx",
"targetGroupArn": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-central-1:496080483451:targetgroup/nginx-443/af722a3b9bf728a3",
"containerPort": 443
}
]
```

Network mode is bridge and instances are correctly attached to each target group listed above with dynamic port mapping. ALB is working correctly but NLB does not resolve healt checks via TCP or HTTPS with path and curl hangs on

```
*   Trying 3.126.131.185...
* TCP_NODELAY set
```

Nginx is configured correctly, running containers locally or accessing via ssh to ec2 host work as expected and nginx respond with 200 OK.
Maybe that bridge mode is not supported on NLB or simply NLB does not start to route traffic to those unhealty instances?

Comment: Don't forget security group settings

Comment: HTTPS TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0 - HTTP TCP 80 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Having the same problem... Any tips?